# The number of symmetric matrices of order 5 with each element either 0 or 1

Tags: matrices

Question is to find The number of symmetric matrices of order 5 with each element either 0 or 1 .

What i am trying is

If i take matrix of order 2

$$A=\left[\matrix{ A & B  \\ B & C \ }\right]$$

Here i am having $2.2.2$ cases in total .Assuming A and C are different .Is thi correct way to generalise to higher order ?  Thanks

Comment: Hint: You just have to see the possible numbers for all the matrix elements in the upper right corner (including diagonal)... You have a choice between $0$ and $1$ for $5+4+3+2+1$ elements...

Comment: @Martigan So for 5 order i will have $2^{15}$ cases ,Right ?

Comment: In fact for a matrix of dimension $k$, you will have $2^{k(k+1)/2}$ matrices.

Comment: @Martigan And for skew symmetric is it $2^{k(k-1)/2}$

Comment: Yes, since you have no choice for the lower left corner AND for the diagonal...

Comment: @Martigan Thanks for helping

Answer (score 2):

Yes your argument is a good start. You may count $n$ the amount of possibly different elements of an upper triangular matrix and then you get $2^n$ binary symmetric matrices.
In the case of matrices $3\times 3$ we have
$$\begin{pmatrix} A_1 & A_2 & A_3 \\ & A_4 & A_5 \\ & & A_6 \end{pmatrix}$$ where $A_1,A_2,A_3,A_4,A_5,A_6 \in \{0,1\}$ so you'll have $2^{6}$ possible matrices (note that the other elements of the matrix are fixed by symmetry). Now, for finding $n$ you may have a look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/185802/dimensions-of-symmetric-and-skew-symmetric-matrices).