# Clarification on finding the dimension of a nxn skew-symmetric matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

I understand that this question has been asked before (here: [Dimensions of symmetric and skew-symmetric matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/185802/dimensions-of-symmetric-and-skew-symmetric-matrices) ).

I understand *why* the matrix has a maximum number of $\frac{n^2-n}{2}$, but why is the number of unique elements of the matrix equal to the dimension? What am I missing here? Thank you.

Edit: I don't know why this has been marked as duplicate as it explicitely states that I'm looking for clarification on this particular question.

Comment: @amWhy I would appreciate it if you would re-open my question as it is clearly not a duplicate.

Comment: What is meant here by "the number of unique elements of the matrix"?

Comment: @coffeemath Sorry, I guess that's kind of ambiguous. In the post I linked (which is ironically the post that I am supposedly duplicating), the reasoning behind finding the dimension of a skew-vector to be what it is is because half of the elements are inverses of the others, and the diagonal is made of zeroes, and thus only $\frac{n^2-n}{2}$ is the dimension. But, $\frac{n^2-n}{2}$ is just the max number of unique elements that one can put in a skew-matrix, isn't it? Why is it also the dimension? Sorry if I'm missing something. Thanks.

Comment: You should work this out on your own anyways. Here's a hint. What is the dimension of the space of all $n\times n$ matrices and why? If you understand this, you should be able to understand why there are less matrices needed to generate the set of all skew-symmetric matrices.

Comment: @palaeomathematician I'm trying to understand, but I just don't. I understand why the dimension of skew-symmetric matrices is less than the dimension of square matrices, but I don't understand why the dimension of square matrices is $n^2$. Help me understand?

Comment: @palaeomathematician The point of this site is to answer questions on mathematics, not to belittle others to stroke your ego.