# compute the dimension of the set of all 3 x 3 symmetric matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

i understand that i need to find a basis for the given set of matrices.

i think i have found one using the set of matrices shown below.

but i am having trouble figuring out how to show linear independence and generation/spanning.

$$ S_1 =
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    \end{pmatrix},
S_2 =
    \begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    \end{pmatrix}, 
S_3 =
    \begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 \\
    \end{pmatrix},$$
$$S_4 =
    \begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 1 & 0 \\
    1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    \end{pmatrix},
S_5 =
    \begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    1 & 0 & 0 \\
    \end{pmatrix},
S_6 =
    \begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

**linear dependence**

for linear independence, i start with a linear combination of the six matrices above.

$a \cdot\!S_1 + b \cdot\!S_2 + c \cdot\!S_3 + d \cdot\!S_4 + e \cdot\!S_5 + f \cdot\!S_6 = 0$

putting each coefficient in the right place(s) creates a new matrix:

$$ A = 
    \begin{pmatrix}
    a & d & e \\
    d & b & f \\
    e & f & c \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

i know this matrix is symmetric because $A = A^t$

$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    a & d & e \\
    d & b & f \\
    e & f & c \\
    \end{pmatrix}^t =
    \begin{pmatrix}
    a & d & e \\
    d & b & f \\
    e & f & c \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

i am stuck here. i'm used to using row operations to show linear independence, but i am unsure of how to implement that here because i am not working with sets of vectors or polynomials. i do not know what to do with matrices because they are already matrices.

should i be using row operations at all though? if i set $a = b = c = d = e = f = 0$, that will give a 3x3 zero matrix and it will show that the only linear combination of the candidate basis matrices is the trivial representation, and that would indicate linear independence. but i am not sure that it's enough to just say this. i think i'm supposed to show it somehow.

**generation/spanning**

i am even more lost here. i would use row operations for this as well and i have with other problems involving sets of vectors and sets of polynomials, but i cannot figure out how to start this part of the problem either.

i realize that if the candidate basis i've chosen is indeed a basis then the dimension i'm looking for is 6, but i'm having trouble showing that this set meets the conditions for being a basis.

Comment: As you noted, you get zero if and only if each coefficient is zero, so you are done with that part; linear independence is proved. This is not unexpected - the space of 3x3 matrices has 9 degrees of freedom (one for each entry). 3 of your matrices use up one degree of freedom, while the other 3 use up two degrees of freedom. Thus all 9 degrees are used up.

Comment: Also, if they are independent then the smallest space they can form is exactly the space using each as a basis vector, which here is dimension 6. Clearly any 3x3 symmetric matrix is realizable this way, so we are done. The general case for $n \times n$ matrices follows almost the same (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/185802/dimensions-of-symmetric-and-skew-symmetric-matrices) for more details)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you say
\begin{align}
a \cdot\!S_1 + b \cdot\!S_2 + c \cdot\!S_3 + d \cdot\!S_4 + e \cdot\!S_5 + f \cdot\!S_6 = 0
\end{align}
the $0$ on the right hand side is the zero vector in the vector space of $3\times3$ matrices. i.e. this equation says
$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    a & d & e \\
    d & b & f \\
    e & f & c \\
    \end{pmatrix}
= \begin{pmatrix}0&0&0\\ 0&0&0\\ 0&0&0\\ \end{pmatrix}$$
Since two matrices are equal iff all their entries are, this immediately implies that $a=b=c=d=e=f=0$,

Spanning is also pretty simple, write down an arbitrary symmetric matrix. Say
$$ A =  \begin{pmatrix}
    a & d & e \\
    d & b & f \\
    e & f & c \\
    \end{pmatrix}$$
it turns out that $A = a \cdot\!S_1 + b \cdot\!S_2 + c \cdot\!S_3 + d \cdot\!S_4 + e \cdot\!S_5 + f \cdot\!S_6  $. That's the end of the proof.